# How many distinct ways are there of seating them at a round table such that every cat is adjacent to two dogs and every dog is adjacent to two cats?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are five cats and five dogs, all distinguishable from one another. How many distinct ways are there of seating them at a round table such that every cat is adjacent to two dogs and every dog is adjacent to two cats? Note that here two orderings are not considered distinct if it is possible to rotate one and achieve the other. For instance, if there are only four seats at the table, the order Cat 1 - Dog 1 - Cat 2 - Dog 2 is the same as Cat 2 - Dog 2 - Cat 1 - Dog 1.

According to Denis's answer, here is mine:
Making dog-1 at the first place, there are 4! ways to place the other 4 dogs at 3,5,7,9. Then we can place the 5 cats at position 2,4,6,8,10, there are 5! ways in total.
I wonder is this final answer 4!*5! correct?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: By rotating, you can make dog-1 sitting on the 1-st ptace. Then the remaining dog positions are 3, 5, 7, 9 and you count all ways to place 4 dogs in these 4 positions and to place 5 cats in the remaining 5 positions.

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.

Comment: A (very) slightly different solution: Count the ways of arranging the animals in a line starting with a dog ($5!5!$), and then divide this by 5 since each circular arrangement was counted exactly 5 times.